# How do I get int values out of a string using two scanner objects?

Tags: java, input, nosuchelementexception

I'm really new to coding and right now I need to take an input from the user in one line seperated by spaces for example "0 1 2" and then take the ints in that string and place them in separate int variables.

This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //takes input from user
input = scan.nextLine();
Scanner intValues = new Scanner(input); //takes input from the "input" variable
```

then I go to place the first int value into a variable and get a "NoSuchElementException"

```
int x = intValues.nextInt();
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also I'm not allowed to use arrays for this assignment.

Comment: is using 2 `scanners` necessary ?, because you could avoid all the confusion by using only one

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use 2 `scanner` to read the input. You can even achieve this using one `scanner`. Like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = scanner.nextInt();
int y = scanner.nextInt();
int z = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: I dont think so. That would need the user to enter 0, enter, 1, enter, 2, enter, instead of, what he wants, 0, space, 1, space, 2, enter

Comment: @user7185318 No it wouldn't.  This works fine as it is, provided there are no characters in there that aren't numbers and aren't white space.

Comment: @DavidWallace : Of course it does so. But have you tested it with the following : `0 1 2` enter ? does this return you x=0, y=1 and z=2 ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Try it.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `hasNext` method on the `Scanner` class to avoid the `NoSuchelementException` exception.

Try the following snippet:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //takes input from user
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    Scanner intValues = new Scanner(input); 
    while(intValues.hasNextInt()) {
        int x = intValues.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Or try the following which uses only one scanner:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //takes input from user
    while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Comment: I think what you are doing wont work for the case with `0 1 2` and then pressing enter…

Comment: better to use hasNextInt here

Comment: @PatrickParker, that's an excellent suggestion. I edited my answer accordingly. thanks much.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but the problem i'm having is that the intValues.nextInt isn't giving me any int values from the string DESPITE the string being literally "0 1 2". 

The while statement is never true in this case and nothing gets put into x, which is a huge problem for the rest of my code.

Comment: @MohdHasan, what is your actual input? is it `0 1 2`?

Comment: Yes, the actual input im using to test out my code is "0 1 2", which is put into variable "input"
I'm trying to put each of the int values, 0 1 and 2 into separate int variables, but i'm running into the issue as I stated above when I try to use a second scanner to get the 3 int values in this string.
I understand that this could be done with just one scanner object but the exercise i'm doing wants me to do it this way...

Comment: @MohdHasan, you need to show your code in that case. I have shown two choices in my answer. Both work fine.